# Working on Mac OS from Windows

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, remote-control

I have a PC with Windows 7 installed - my colleague has a Mac Mini with Snow Leopard.
I know that I can use VNC to access to his OS but only to the active session. I want to keep my friend working in his session and create another profile on the Mac Mini.

Is it possible to connect to the new session without bothering the active session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Vine Server](https://www.testplant.com/products/vine/) for a possible solution.

Another free possibility, from [Use multiple simulataneous GUI accounts](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050808134043984) :

> Here's how to have two GUI users
>   active at one time on the same
>   machine. This hint is a summary of
>   [this hint](http://www.macosx.com/forums/showthread.php?t=52547) on the macosx.com
>   forums; read the original post for
>   much more detail.
>
> Here are the basic requirements:
>
> - [Vine Viewer](http://www.testplant.com/products/vine_viewer)
> - Mac OS X 10.4
> - Multiple user accounts on the system
>
> After you have two or more accounts
>   set up on one Mac, install Vine Viewer and
>   start the server. Once started, Fast
>   User Switch to the other user on the
>   machine.
>
> Now from another computer, use a VNC
>   viewer like [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) and
>   point it to the Mac. Even though the
>   Mac is logged in as another user, your
>   VNC session goes to the original
>   account, allowing both of you to use
>   the machine at the same time.

Comment: Is there a free alternative?

Comment: @Zakaria: See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

mac mini must have server OS X and Aqua Connect

http://www.aquaconnect.net/mac-terminal-server.php

Comment: Is there a free alternative?